# AJAX request doesn't execute fail on 400 bad query

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm sending this request, and it is perfectly fine as long as it's successful. However, if I try to create a user with existing username or email, I should get `400 bad request` and response detailing what's the problem.

Thing is, when I send this request and get 400, nothing gets written to console/console (not even the `'fail!'` string), but I can see that response is correct in console/network tab so the problem is probably not in the backend.

```
$("#registerForm").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "./register",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({
      "username": formcontent['username'],
      "email": formcontent['email'],
      "password": formcontent['password'],
    }),
    success: function(e) {
      window.location.href = './login'
      return false
    },
    fail: function(e) {
      console.log('fail!')
      console.log(e)
      //react to error
      return false
    },
  })
})
```

Comment: try `error:` in stead of `fail:`.. or better yet `$.ajax({}).done(function(){}).fail(function(){});`

Comment: Yup, worked. I should research more before asking.

Answer (score 1):

I think 'fail' is a invalid function, Please try with below structure

```
$.ajax({
type : "POST",
url : "/register",
contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType : "json",
data : JSON.stringify({
    "username" : formcontent['username'],
    "email" : formcontent['email'],
    "password" : formcontent['password'],
}),
success : function(response) {
    console.log(response);
},
error : function(response, status, err) {
    console.log(response);
    console.log(status);
    console.log(err);
}
});
```